# Gamma function approximation

Tags: approximation, gamma-function

I found this approximation online:

> When $h \to 0$,  $\dfrac{\Gamma(h+\alpha)\cdot h}{\Gamma(h+1)}\sim \Gamma(\alpha)\cdot h$

How is this so, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\Gamma(h+\alpha) \;h}{\Gamma(h+1)\;\Gamma(\alpha)\; h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\Gamma(h+\alpha) }{\Gamma(h+1)\;\Gamma(\alpha)}\underbrace{=}_{\Gamma\text{ continuous}}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\alpha)}=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $ x \mapsto \Gamma(\cdot)$ is a *continuous function*, as $h \to 0$, one has
$$
\Gamma(h+\alpha) \sim \Gamma(0+\alpha)=\Gamma(\alpha), \quad \Gamma(h+1)\sim \Gamma(1)=1
$$ giving
$$
\dfrac{\Gamma(h+\alpha)\cdot h}{\Gamma(h+1)}\sim \dfrac{\Gamma(0+\alpha)\cdot h}{\Gamma(0+1)}=\Gamma(\alpha)\cdot h
$$

Comment: What about the multiplication by h ?

Comment: Many thanks for your help

Comment: @user401988 You can neglect $h$ in a sum $h+\alpha$ ($\alpha \neq0$), but you *can't* neglect $h$ *alone*.

Comment: @user401988 You are welcome.